# Windows Batch: For Block with variable within variable

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop, delayedvariableexpansion

I want to make a variable Variable, which means that i want to create many variables with **variable** names, e.g. Var**1**, Var**2**, Var**3**, Var**4**. This works (see below), but `ECHO`ing was not working since i have to use `EnableDelayedExpansion` due to single handling within the `FOR`-Loop and `!var%num%!` was not interpreted correctly.

So here is what i've got:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET /a num = 0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b *.bat') DO (
    SET /a num = num + 1
    SET var!num!=%%a
    CALL ECHO No. !num!^: %%var!num!%%
    )

EndLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
```

After hours, this works now using the `CALL`-Routine in front of echo

My question to you guys out there is now how to make

```
    CALL ECHO No. !num!^: %%var!num!%%
```

a little nicer. I first tried

```
    ECHO No. !Num!^: !var%num%!
```

but this fails as it is in on single `FOR`-Loop. Is there any opportunity to make this nicer than `CALLING` it?

Thank you in advance
Patrick

Comment: The right term for your "variable within variable" is _array_. See: [arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, that was absolutely what i've searched for.

Answer (score 3):

```dos
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET /a "num=0"

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b *.bat') DO (
    SET /a "num+=1"
    SET "var!num!=%%a"
    FOR %%b in (!num!) do ECHO No. !num!: !var%%b!
)

EndLocal
```